# OSX/ObjectiveC: List all the objects created in the heap by my app

Tags: objective-c, macos, heap-memory

Is it possible to list all the objects that lives in the heap and have been created by my app?
I think it's possible, Instruments do something like this.

Comment: Of course it is, `free()` and `malloc()` need to store their data somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

**Instruments**

In instruments, choose the **Allocations** template in the **Memory** system and you'll have the ability to look at all objects that are either *live* in the heap, or which have *ever been allocated* in the heap.

There's reasonably good filtering in here as well, and if you have lots of memory, or an app that doesn't create/destroy a lot of objects, you can even track reference counts.

**Code**

There isn't an API to look into the malloc/free data structures officially, so if you have a compelling non-debugging need to look at individual allocs, you're probably looking at replacing the standard memory allocation routines with a specialized instrumented version (kind of like what guard malloc does -[Guard Malloc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html)).